# Heroku H12 Request timeout on Django application

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I am running a Django application on Heroku.

when i make a request longer than 30 seconds, it stopped and the request returns 503 Service Unavailable.

These are the heroku logs

```
2021-10-20T07:11:14.726613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/ajax/download_yt/" host=yeti-mp3.herokuapp.com request_id=293289be-6484-4f11-a62d-bda6d0819351 fwd="79.3.90.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I tried to do some research on that and i found that i could increase the gunicorn (i am using gunicorn version 20.0.4) timeout in the Procfile. I tried increasing to 60 seconds, but the request still stops after 30.

This is my current Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn yetiMP3.wsgi --timeout 60 --log-file -
```

these are the buildpacks i'm using on my heroku app:

- heroku/python
- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

How can i increase the request timeout?
Did i miss some heroku configuration?

Comment: Why do you have 30+ second response times? Seems a little excessive

Comment: It's a request to a controller that download youtube videos. I should do it as a background process, but i want to understand what i am doing wrong with heroku configuration

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i found that it's a Heroku dyno configuration.
The Heroku router will drop any request after 30 seconds, no matter how high you set the gunicorn timer.

More details in this official heroku [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preventing-h12-errors-request-timeouts#add-a-timeout-to-the-webserver)